# Server 2003/2008: DNS server has updated its own host (A) records

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

All of our DNS servers (Win2003/2008) keep reporting this error over and over, once a day. DNS is otherwise working fine. It's simply annoying at this point, but I'd love to get rid of it (it's clogging our monitoring tools). I have verified that the AD rep partners all have the IPs for the servers.

```
DNS server has updated its own host (A) records.  In order to ensure that its DS-integrated peer DNS servers are able to replicate with this server, an attempt was made to update them with the new records through dynamic update.  An error was encountered during this update, the record data is the error code. 

If this DNS server does not have any DS-integrated peers, then this error 
should be ignored. 

If this DNS server's Active Directory replication partners do not have the correct IP address(es) for this server, they will be unable to replicate with it. 

To ensure proper replication: 
1) Find this server's Active Directory replication partners that run the DNS server. 
2) Open DnsManager and connect in turn to each of the replication partners. 
3) On each server, check the host (A record) registration for THIS server. 
4) Delete any A records that do NOT correspond to IP addresses of this server. 
5) If there are no A records for this server, add at least one A record corresponding to an address on this server, that the replication partner can contact.  (In other words, if there multiple IP addresses for this DNS server, add at least one that is on the same network as the Active Directory DNS server you are updating.) 
6) Note, that is not necessary to update EVERY replication partner.  It is only necessary that the records are fixed up on enough replication partners so that every server that replicates with this server will receive (through replication) the new data.
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the server have more than one network interface card?
Are any of them DHCP-enabled?
If there are more than one NIC, only one should be allowed to register it's records in DNS, for a number of reasons.

Updated answer:

Even your DC can be a DHCP client... It's just a *very* *bad* *idea*.. :)
I'd uncheck "Register in DNS" for all but ONE static IP, that way the server will only use the one IP for AD services.

If your server has NIC's in different separated subnets, and you need AD services in all networks, you're in trouble, because clients will some times get the reachable IP for your DC, but some times they will receive the unreachable one. In this case you need to create Sites in AD and connect subnets to each one

Comment: Most of them have more than one NIC, one doesn't (it's a VM). None have DHCP (can DNS servers even BE dhcp?) All have "Register in DNS" checked for only the static/allocated IPs

Comment: "can DNS servers BE dhcp?" - well, Weird Al Yankovic answered this best decades ago - "It slices, it dices ~ Look at that tomato ~ You could even cut a tin can with it ~ But you wouldn't want to" - Mr. Popeil, "In 3-D", 1984 - yes, it is possible to set up a server that has DNS service but has DHCP for the IP addresses...but it's about as useful as a solar-powered batteryless flashlight.  NOTE: I do not know if Win2k3 Server actively checks/forbids this arrangement...but I can easily cook up a *nix box to do what I describe.

Answer (score 1):

Put a static A record in DNS for the IP address and turn off "Register in DNS".